# Data quality - check if all values in a character column are numbers in R

Tags: r, data-quality

I am looking to perform data quality on numerous system generated tables. One of the checks is to see if all values in a character column are only numbers. I am looking to know the number columns where this check is true. Using the following table as an example I would want to identify that  two columns (code and age) are character columns that consist of only numeric values.

**Table Structure**

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| name | character |
| type | character |
| code | character |
| member_id | integer |
| collection_date | date |
| age | character |
| height | double |

**Table Values**

| Column Name | Column Values |
| --- | --- |
| name | only letters |
| type | only letters |
| code | only numbers |
| member_id | only numbers |
| collection_date | only dates |
| age | only numbers |
| height | only numbers |

I am having issues thinking of the logic that is required to do this. What I have done thus far is:

To select only columns that are character data types

```
df %>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.character)
```

To validate that all values in the column are numeric (or null, which is fine)

```
sum(varhandle::check.numeric(df$code)) == nrow(df)
```

I am hoping to build a function that performs this across all columns and stores the number where the check is true into a column (i.e. dplyr::mutate), but I am not sure how to structure this; is it an across, an apply, or something else. Or is there any existing function/package that would perform this task? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could construct the condition within `select` itself

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
   select(where(~ all(varhandle::check.numeric(.))))
```

---

It is not clear whether `numeric` columns with mismatched type or columns having some character elements and thus got converted to `class` `character`.  If it is the former, then add a `type.convert` before the `select` and then get only the numeric columns

```
df %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
   select(where(is.numeric))
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect and really simple, much appreciated!